# Windows 10 UWP - How to make app dock at window edge and foldout

Tags: c#, uwp, slide, windows-10-universal

I'm planning the development of a fairly simple app and have little experience with UWP, some with Winforms. I'd like to make it so that the user can dock the app (similar to the taskbar, but the size of a browser tab) to the edge of the screen and allow it to slide in/out on click or hover. Searches have turned up nothing (maybe I'm not using the right terms) and I've yet to see this functionality on a Windows 10 app.

I'm thinking that I could just force the window to be offscreen or have a 0 width. But I'm not certain how to make a tab appear when that happens. Would I make a second window that is the tab?

All constructive thoughts and ideas are welcome.

Comment: Use WinForms or WPF, you can't with UWP

Comment: Ah that's a bummer. No big worry though. Thanks for the input. I have more experience with Winforms anyway. Cheers!